# how to get upload file name in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, upload

Hi i'm trying to upload image to a folder and image name in  database

in view

```
echo form_open_multipart('subscribers_c/actioncreate',array('class'=>'form'));`enter code here`
<input type='file' name='img'>
```

in controller

```
$config['upload_path'] ='./assets/uploads/subscribers_photos'; //The path where the image will be save
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; //Images extensions accepted
        $config['max_size']    = '2048'; 
        $config['max_width']  = '1024'; 
        $config['max_height']  = '768'; 
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE; 
        $this->load->library('upload', $config); //Load the upload CI library
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('img'))
        {
            $uploadError = array('upload_error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            //$this->set_flashdata('msg_error', $uploadError, site_url().'/subscribers_c/actioncreate'); 
        }
        $file_info = $this->upload->data('img');
        $img_name = $file_info['file_name']; 

        $data=array(
            'chit_fund_id'=>$this->input->post('cid'),
            'first_name'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
            'last_name'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
            'dob'=>$this->input->post('bd'),
            'gender'=>$this->input->post('g'),
            'contact_number'=>$this->input->post('mob'),
            'address'=>$this->input->post('add'),
            'email_id'=>$this->input->post('eml'),
            'bid_status'=>$this->input->post('b_status'),
            'user_status'=>$this->input->post('u_status'),
            'image_name'=>$img_name,
        );
        //print_r($data);
```

image_name is not having any value
how to get image name .

Comment: What does your form look like? Does it contain a enctype? Do you `$_POST` the image? That is something that doesn't work.

Comment: it is form_open_multipart()

Answer (score 3):

Instead of img in upload data

```
$file_info = $this->upload->data('img');
```

Try

```
$file_info = $this->upload->data();
$img = $file_info['file_name'];
```

And on here `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/subscribers_photos';` end with `/`

Like `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/subscribers_photos/';`

Comment: i tried $img_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');  this is working fine.

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/subscribers_photos/'; this is not working my code is fine..

Comment: Is it not inserting into db is the image column name varchar 255

Comment: But I do not see where your insert function is for db on controller

Answer (score 1):

Inside the view call the form_upload function(if needed, your one is also correct):

```
<?php echo form_upload('pic'); ?>
```

Inside controller function for upload:

```
$img_name = $_FILES["pic"]["name"];
```

By using this code you will get the file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$img_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
```

Comment: Even if it could help, posting just a line of code isn't a good answer. Please have a look at [answer] and add some explanation as at the moment it is a very low quality and will get deleted soon.